# IE 11では思ったように星の色が変わりません。

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

星にマウスを乗せた時、色がつくように実装をしております。
Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Safariでは問題なく期待通りに動きますが、
なぜかIE11では星が1つのサイズしか色がつかないです。

下記がソースコードになります。

```
<html>

  <style>
    .select-star-rating {
      font-size: 0;
      white-space: nowrap;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 250px;
      height: 50px;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjREREREREIiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
      background-size: contain;
  }
  .select-star-rating > i {
      opacity: 0;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 20%;
      z-index: 1;
      background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
      background-size: contain;
  }
  .select-star-rating > input {
      -moz-appearance: none;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      opacity: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 20%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      z-index: 2;
      position: relative;
  }

  .select-star-rating > input:hover + i, input:checked + i {
      opacity: 1;
  }

  .select-star-rating > i ~ i{
      width: 40%;
  }
  .select-star-rating >i ~ i ~ i{
      width: 60%;
  }
  .select-star-rating >i ~ i ~ i ~ i{
      width: 80%;
  }
  .select-star-rating >i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i{
      width: 100%;
  }

  </style>
  <body>

    <span class="select-star-rating">
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"><i></i>
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><i></i>
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"><i></i>
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4"><i></i>
      <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5"><i></i>
    </span>

  </body>
</html>
```

マウスを五つ目の星に乗せた場合

**[IE11]**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**[Chrome]**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

何かアドバイスをいただければと思います。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

※私は原因を明確に説明出来るほど今回の IE11 の動作を理解していないので、問題を解決するまでに行った作業の手順を示します。

まずは、 `background-image` プロパティへ設定している値を png ファイルへと替えたものを、 IE11 で動作させました。すると無事に動作したことから、インライン SVG を背景画像として使用している状況に原因があると推測出来ます。

```css
.select-star-rating {
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjREREREREIiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
  background-size: contain;
}

.select-star-rating>i {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url('http://placehold.jp/50x50.png');
  background-size: contain;
}

.select-star-rating>input {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.select-star-rating>input:hover+i,
input:checked+i {
  opacity: 1;
}

.select-star-rating>i~i {
  width: 40%;
}

.select-star-rating>i~i~i {
  width: 60%;
}

.select-star-rating>i~i~i~i {
  width: 80%;
}

.select-star-rating>i~i~i~i~i {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-star-rating">
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5"><i></i>
</div>
```

そこで、この推測と類似する記事がないか探したところ、以下のような Web サイトが見つかりました。これによれば、 `width`, `height` 属性が設定されていない場合に、**スケーリングが適切に行われない**ことがあるようです。これより、ホバーしたときに IE11 では星がひとつしか青くならない原因は、スケーリングが適切に行われていないためではないかと推測出来ます。

> #### Wrapping Up <sup>[[1]](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-style-inheritance-and-fousvg/)</sup>
>
> Having explicit, non-percentage width and height values set on an SVG not only helps with fixing FOUSVG issues, but it also helps with other scaling problems, especially when the SVG is used as a background image in CSS. Internet Explorer sometimes refuses to scale the image properly if it doesn’t have its aspect ratio specified with the width and height attributes. I’ve had this happen even with non-background images recently as well.

そこで、青い星の SVG へ `width`, `height` 属性を追加し、

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.1.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->

<svg version="1.1" id="_x32_" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="width: 48px; height: 48px; opacity: 1;" xml:space="preserve" width="48" height="48">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#4B4B4B;}
</style>
<g>
    <path class="st0" d="M510.698,196.593c-3.61-11.2-14.034-18.795-25.794-18.795H329.21L281.791,30.155
        c-3.599-11.2-14.018-18.808-25.791-18.808c-11.772,0-22.192,7.608-25.791,18.808l-47.418,147.642H27.097
        c-11.761,0-22.185,7.594-25.795,18.795c-3.599,11.2,0.436,23.449,9.999,30.302l126.246,90.643l-48.598,147.54
        c-3.694,11.193,0.278,23.47,9.801,30.398c9.529,6.926,22.44,6.897,31.94-0.058L256,403.594l125.312,91.824
        c9.5,6.956,22.411,6.985,31.941,0.058c9.522-6.927,13.494-19.205,9.811-30.398l-48.61-147.54L500.7,226.895
        C510.262,220.042,514.298,207.792,510.698,196.593z" style="fill: rgb(33, 150, 243);"></path>
</g>
</svg>
```

これを使い CSS を以下のように修正したところ、 IE11 においても Firefox や Chrome のような動作が得られました。

```css
.select-star-rating {
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjREREREREIiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
  background-size: contain;
}

.select-star-rating>i {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  background-size: contain;
}

.select-star-rating>input {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.select-star-rating>input:hover+i,
input:checked+i {
  opacity: 1;
}

.select-star-rating>i~i {
  width: 40%;
}

.select-star-rating>i~i~i {
  width: 60%;
}

.select-star-rating>i~i~i~i {
  width: 80%;
}

.select-star-rating>i~i~i~i~i {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-star-rating">
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5"><i></i>
</div>
```

---

参考:

- [SVG Style Inheritance and the ‘Flash Of Unstyled SVG’ — Sara Soueidan – Freelance-Front-End UI/UX Developer](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-style-inheritance-and-fousvg/)
- [css - IE11 using svg as background-image fails - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225933/ie11-using-svg-as-background-image-fails)
- [IE9-11で背景画像のSVGの表示が崩れる問題と対処法 - 週刊SVG](https://web.archive.org/web/20160809010837/http://ssvvgg.net/post/140503977275/ie9-11%E3%81%A7%E8%83%8C%E6%99%AF%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E3%81%AEsvg%E3%81%AE%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%8C%E5%B4%A9%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C%E3%81%A8%E5%AF%BE%E5%87%A6%E6%B3%95)
- [The Different Ways of Getting SVG Out of Adobe Illustrator | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/illustrator-to-svg/)

Comment: > 遅くなりました！丁寧に説明していただきありがとうございます。まさにSVGの中に
width, heightが設定されてないのが原因でした。